# Dynamic variable through localStorage and url param

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic variable

Example:

```
dynamic = "music1"
```

This variable is changing and I want to keep this variable using localStorage instead of a cookie:

```
localStorage.setItem('dynamic', dynamic)
```

I would like to use this variable as query parameter is the url contains in the url i.e. library.

Example the current url is:

`www.domain.com/library` if in the storage exist a variable change the url to something like this:

```
www.domain.com/library?dynamic=music1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this answers what you were asking

```
var dynamic = 'music1';
var url = 'www.domain.com/library';

localStorage.setItem('dynamic', dynamic);

if(localStorage.getItem('dynamic') != null){
    var storedVariable = localStorage.getItem('dynamic');
    url += '?dynamic=' + storedVariable;
}
```

Hope that helps ;)